# Luis Out of call volume quota

Tags: azure, azure-language-understanding

I have a Luis application and I am using the starter key for development. I am getting

> Out of call volume quota. Quota will be replenished in xxxxxxxx.

I know that you have 1000 query per month but I only used 188 ( value on the dashboard). Is there another reason for getting out of Quota?

Answer (score 3):

Are you working with the starter key?

The starter key only allows 1000 calls per month and doesn't work fine.

Here you have an extract from Microsoft FAQ:

> **Why did I get an email saying I'm almost out of quota?**
>
> Your authoring/starter key is only allowed 1000 endpoint queries a month.
> Create a LUIS subscription key (free or paid) and use that key when
> making endpoint queries. If you are making endpoint queries from a bot
> or another client application, you need to change the LUIS endpoint
> key there.

***[Check this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/manage-keys) to know how to create a LUIS Key.***

Comment: I only made 200 calls

Comment: @LonsomeHell sometime it takes about a week to update the current usages. If you have another LUIS App using the Starter Key, it will also count the usages of that.