# LUIS Operation returned an invalid status code 'Unauthorized' BotFramework v4

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-language-understanding

Good day all.

My bot become getting error: **Operation returned an invalid status code 'Unauthorized'** while getting result from LUIS.ai.

- "Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.Luis" Version="4.2.2"
- "Microsoft.Bot.Builder" Version="4.2.2"

This issue appeared today.

I tried to re-publish bot, but It doesn`t work.

This issue is present on localhost and on Azure throught remote debug too...

StackTrace:    at Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Language.LUIS.Runtime.Prediction.d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Language.LUIS.Runtime.PredictionExtensions.d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.Luis.LuisRecognizer.d__23.MoveNext() in D:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.LUIS\LuisRecognizer.cs:line 421
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.Luis.LuisRecognizer.d__10.MoveNext() in D:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.LUIS\LuisRecognizer.cs:line 112
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at AxactorBotApp.AxactorBot.<DetectIntentAndEntitiesAsync>d__13.MoveNext() in D:\Work\Miratech\Axactor\Axactor\Web\AppServices\AxactorBotApp\AxactorBot.cs:line 175
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at AxactorBotApp.AxactorBot.d__12.MoveNext() in D:\Work\Miratech\Axactor\Axactor\Web\AppServices\AxactorBotApp\AxactorBot.cs:line 79
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.MiddlewareSet.d__3.MoveNext() in D:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder\MiddlewareSet.cs:line 55
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.BotAdapter.d__13.MoveNext() in D:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder\BotAdapter.cs:line 167

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved. I was out of Quota in Luis.

The answer was fount here: [Luis Out of call volume quota](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49112699/luis-out-of-call-volume-quota)